# Publishing to S3 in electron-builder gives me some weird artifacts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, electron, electron-builder

I'm working on https://github.com/Jigsaw-Code/outline-client trying to publish our binaries to S3 instead of Github.

In src/electron/release_linux_action.sh I've changed the invocation of electron-builder to use

`--config.publish.provider=s3 \
--config.publish.bucket=*my-play-bucket-name*`

I have my credentials in ~/.aws/credentials

Instead of our usual artifacts being published, my bucket now contains a bunch of tiny, weirdly named files

Downloading and inspecting these files shows that they're logs of HTTP/1.1 sessions:

> ...
>   "PUT /my-bucket-name/2019-05-01-17-25-02-2391717FC94ECECB HTTP/1.1" 200...
>   ...

This is obviously not what anyone wants, but I'm not sure where to go from here.  I can `aws s3 sync` our build directory to the bucket just fine, but that would involve giving the project a dependency on the aws cli and make us responsible for publishing correctly as opposed to letting electron-builder do it for us.  Any ideas?